# Cypress Automation how can I call on feature file in another feature file

Tags: cypress

I am using cucumber in cypress and I have multiple feature files.One of my feature files depend on another feature file. is it possible to call different feature file in a feature file?
so In order to run JJ.feature file, I have to have it run test2.feature file first

This is in a case that I want to just run JJ.feature and that is dependent

```
--> integeration folder
        |
        ---> test folder
               |
                 ---> login.feature
               |---> login folder --> login.js
               |---> test2.featuer (@login then all then run the rest Scenario)
                |---- test2 folder -> test.js(it should run login first)
                |---> JJ.featuer (@login @test1 and @test2 needs to run first then all then run the rest Scenario)
                |---- JJ folder -> jj.js(it should run login first)
```